# Active accordion content pushes everything up

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I'm making this accordion: https://codepen.io/rafaelmollad/pen/JjRZbeW but the problem is that when I click on one of the accordion item, the content expands and pushes the title up. I noticed that if the accordion is not vertically centered, then I get the result that I want but I need to center it.
I've added this code to the container in order to center it but it doesn't work:

```
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%)
```

If I remove those lines, the form will position on the top of the page and I'll get the result that I want (without the container being in the center of the page)

Comment: So what you need is, the accordion's top side must stay in place when its height changes, even if it means that it will no longer be centered when expanded?

Comment: @Rod911 I want the accordion's top side to stay in the same place and I want it to be centered on the page. I'd like the container to grow downwards every time I click on an accordion item.

Answer (score 0):

Update your container class like

```
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 96rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
/*   transform: translateY(-50%); */
}
```

i.e remove transform property, it works exactly like you want.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. That's true but if I remove the transform property the accordion won't be centered.

Comment: try updating your top property to use calc in css like `top: calc(50% - 15%)` it will be enough to keep content at center.

Comment: Thanks I came up with this solution:
    position: absolute;
    top: calc((viewport-height / 2) - container-height / 2);
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing the exact solution.